# How to optimize NOT IN query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM '.PRFX.'sell 
WHERE draft = "0" '.$e_sql.' 
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT id_ FROM '.PRFX.'skipped WHERE uid = "'.$u.'") 
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT id_ FROM '.PRFX.'followed WHERE uid = "'.$u.'") 
ORDER BY raised DESC '.$sql_limit
```

Using e.g. join (would it help)?

Comment: Not sure about mysql but using `NOT EXISTS` is typically faster than using `NOT IN`. (assuming you are optimizing for speed).

Comment: The two subselects could be combined with a `UNION`, but answering the question correctly involves also knowing what size are the tables, what indexes there are, what is the current query plan, etc.

Comment: I agree with @KouberSaparev without knowing indexes, table size or anything, we cannot give you any clue on how to proceed. Everything is relevant to the solution. It doesn't matter how you write your query, it all relates to how your schema structure is, including indexes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just learning SQL in school so I'll do my best to submit a decent answer.

If you want to have your subquery tables' join you could probably use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM '.PRFX.'sell 
WHERE draft = "0" 
'.$e_sql.' 
AND ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT id_ 
    FROM '.PRFX.'skipped 
    WHERE uid = "'.$u.'") AS idSkipped
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id_ 
    FROM '.PRFX.'followed 
    WHERE uid = "'.$u.'") AS idFollowed
    ON idSkipped.id_ = idFollowed.id_
ORDER BY raised DESC '.$sql_limit'
```

You may not want to use INNER JOIN becouse it will throw away any id_ if it's not found in the other table.

I hope this helped!
Bert